# Lpsolve matlab installation error

Tags: matlab, lpsolve

The error is:

```
Error using mxlpsolve 
Failed to initialise lpsolve library.
```

I run the

> Makefile.m

in the folder and the compiliation, it says everything compiled fine. Where do i need to put mslpsolve and where do i find it?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following guide to solve the same problem:

http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Re-lpsolve-in-MATLAB-on-Mac-OS-X-10-8-2-td1770.html

the only thing that was missed within the guide and I added it up is as follows:

```
$ cd $HOME/Documents/MATLAB/lp_solve_5.5/extra/MATLAB/lpsolve
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/liblpsolve55.dylib liblpsolve55.so
```

make sure that you have installed lp_solve package already.